# Why does Photoshop's Zoom Tool disengage randomly?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, tools, shortcuts, zoom

This happens all the time and it's driving me crazy... I press <kbd>Z</kbd> to switch to the **Zoom Tool**. Then I click-drag somewhere to zoom in, but *instead Ps has switched back to the **Grab Tool***, so I end up dragging some piece of artwork out of place instead of zooming as intended.

Sometimes even after pressing <kbd>Z</kbd> an extra time it still happens. I've gotten into the habit of hitting the key three times before zooming, just to let Photoshop know that, yes, I am serious about wanting to zoom. That is actually what I want to do. Not Grab. Not any other operation. Zoom. <kbd>Z</kbd> key...

Is anyone else experiencing this? Is there a way to solve it?

<sup>Photoshop 24.2.0, macOS 12.6</sup>

Comment: This is likely to require a specific setup or configuration. I can't repro, then again I never use the zoom tool itself, I just hold Opt & scroll. [I don't use the hand tool either, Spacebar & drag…] btw, moving the artwork is Move [v], not 'grab' [which doesn't exist]

Comment: There's a tool?? `:)` I just hold `Command/Ctrl`+`Space` to zoom in... add `Option/Alt` to zoom out. If I had to guess, I'd speculate you may be inadvertently hitting other keys.. like the `H` which switches to the Grab tool.

Comment: @Tetsujin lol "Grab" is the Blender equivalent. Sorry for the confusion. In my mind, when I hit **V** in Ps, I'm "grabbing". I meant "Move". Switching to Opt+Scroll might serve me better. I'll try it out. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The zoom works just fine in my Photoshop 24.1.1/PC.

Make sure your keyboard is working, or try another keyboard. If there's a faulty button on your keyboard it could trigger shortcuts. If you use a laptop, try both the laptop keyboard, and any external keyboard you may be using.

Try resetting PS preferences.

Try deactivating all the zooming options under Preferences > Tools.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm wondering if it may be related to the 'spring-loaded' tool shortcuts preference.  You may try turning that setting off in Preferences/Tools.  It functions to revert a tool to a previous when the keyboard shortcut is pressed briefly.  I was having a similar issue and this is what fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same issue and it has driven me nuts as well. It comes indeed from the spring loaded tool shortcuts. Just increase the timing sensitivy and you'll be god :)